# Make sure the image is loaded before print preview in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```
     <section class="col-xs-6">
     <img ng-src = "{{ecard.secondaryLogoUrl}}" >
 </section>
 <section class="col-xs-6">
             <!-- Make sure image is loaded and then print the ecard -->
             <img ng-src="{{ecard.templateUrl}}" alt="" onload="window.print()" >           
 </section>
```

In my angularjs application I have 2 images to be shown for the print preview. If I call window.print() method from the second section the first section image is not loaded. How can I make sure both the images are loaded properly before calling window.print() method. 
Thanks
Manohar

Answer (score 0):

You can set a scope watcher on the variable and check the properties

```
$scope.$watch('ecard', function(new, old) {
  // check if both images are present
  if (new && new.secondaryLogoUrl && new.templateUrl) {
    window.print();
  }
})
```